# Sum values in a column based on conditions in other column and also change values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry for disturbing you all. If somebody help me out in this problem I shall be grateful to you. Thanks in anticipation.

I need a Formula in Excel  to Calculate Sum of values in a Column based on conditions in 2nd Columns.

If somebody can provide me formula for that then I shall be grateful to u.

Example:

I want to sum all values that contain y and normalize their value to 100% and then add else values in that.

Means (0.0% +5.0%+5.0% …..=100%) + 3.4% for opt +0.0% nur fur OKO + 5.0% for EPH1 bei anfrage etc

Means else are added normally. So total will become 100%+ 3.4%+5.0% etc…

I have use formula like =SUMIF(F5:F31;"y";E5:E31) but it only sums values which are (y). I want to sum values for y and convert them to 100% at the end and also add other values in that .

```
 Evaluation parameter
     0,0%   y
     3,4%   opt
     5,0%   y
     0,0%   nur für OKO
     0,0%   n
     5,0%   y
     3,4%   y
     3,4%   y
     3,4%   delete
     3,4%   y
     3,4%   y
     3,4%   y
     3,4%   y
     3,4%   y
     0,3%   y
     3,4%   y
     3,4%   y
     3,4%   y
     5,0%   y
     3,4%   y
     3,4%   opt
     5,0%   EPH1 bei Abfrage 
     0,0%   delete
     3,4%   opt
     3,4%   y
     3,4%   y
     0,0%   delete
    Sum=120% etc    (Means sum will be grater than 100% )
```

Make it more simple

```
    1%   y
    2%   EPH
    3%   y
    4%   delete
    5%   n
    Sum= (1%+3%+5%)=100%)+2%+4% = Total
```

Means add values for “y”  ( 1%+3%+5%)=100%) and make their sum to 100% and 
then add other values like 2%,4% in 100%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just going to normalize "y" values to 100% then counting them seems redundant.
Why not do the following?

```
=1+SUMIF(F:F,"<>y",E:E)
```

Comment: Perfect . It worked smoothly.Thanks a lot .One thing if I don't want to show roundoff also . Right now I am getting Value like 119% but original value is 118.6% . Is there any solution for this also.

Comment: Not sure i quite understand but you can format the cell as either a number or percentage with the desired amount of decimal places to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry question was regarding roundoff . Can I keep the value without roundoff.E.g I want the value to be 118.6% but in excel it is 119% that i am getting.

Comment: Excel isn't doing any rounding in this example. Check that your source data contains the appropriate level of depth and that you're not using any other formulae in this situation.

Comment: Perfect @zerk I got it . Thanks a lot. Its a button in Excel at Home like Increase decimal no. so it shows without roundoff values. Thanks once again.